# How to prevent copying nothing to clipboard in VisualStudio2015?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, copy, copy-paste, paste

This is a super annoying thing with Visual Studio 2015 where if I have a segment of code copied to my clip board and I got to paste it on an empty line but instead make the mistake of pressing `Ctrl + C` then it erases my copied code and attaches a blank line to the clipboard. Is there a way of preventing this? I'm assuming no but I figured I'd ask to make sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be you are looking for this one-

Goto Tools > Options > Text Editor > All Languages > and uncheck 'Apply Cut or Copy Commands to blank lines when there is no selection' option like below-

[image: copy-paste]